# How to add content before ::marker in CSS?

Tags: css, marker

```
ol::before:marker {
    
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #00b7a8; 
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; 
    content: '√';
}
```

I want to add "√" before **::marker** element and this is my CSS code, but it's no use，could you help me?

Comment: `::marker` should be on `<li>` not `<ol>`. Is your HTML typical? ex. `<ol><li>..</i>,...</ol>`?

Comment: This HTML is generated by hugo，its structure is <ol><li id="fn:1">::marker<p></li>,...</ol>.
I just want add one special symbol before ::marker, this is my CSS code, but it's no use:
li::before:marker {
    
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #00b7a8; 
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: '[';
}

Comment: So it's a `<li>` not a `<ol>`?

Comment: Please put into your question exactly the HTML that is generated for that list. The HTML in your comment makes no sense with ::marker inside it as ::marker is from CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a class then use `:nth-*` to specify which `<li>` to style. Just style the `::marker` pseudo-element, it gets too crowded with `::before` added in. The `content:` can be manually filled. The normal `::marker` for a `<li>` inside an `<ol>` is a number and a dot (ex: 1.) so include that and add anything behind it, in front of it, etc..

```css
li:first-of-type::marker {
  content: '✔️/*space*/1./*space*/' 
}
```

```css
li:first-of-type::marker {
  content: '✔️ 1. ';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>...I</li>
  <li>...II</li>
  <li>...III</li>
  <li>...IV</li>
  <li>...V</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Add symbol with class

```css
ol>li.checked::marker {
  content: "√ " counter(list-item) ". ";
}

ul>li.checked::before {
  content: "√";
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: 21px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Ordered</h3>

<ol>
  <li class='checked'>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li class='checked'>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ol>

<h3>Unordered</h3>

<ul>
  <li class='checked'>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li class='checked'>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ul>

<h3>Nested list</h3>

<ul>
  <li class='checked'>
    <ol>
      <li class='checked'>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li class='checked'>item 3</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class='checked'>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li class='checked'>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li class='checked'>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

#### Add symbol without class

```css
ol>li::marker {
  content: "√ " counter(list-item) ". ";
}

ul>li::before {
  content: "√";
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: 21px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Ordered</h3>

<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ol>

<h3>Unordered</h3>

<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
</ul>

<h3>Nested list</h3>

<ul>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my CSS code is generated bu hugo automaticly. It's not convenient for me with the method adding class label.

Comment: You need `li` always have symbol?

Comment: yes, before ::marker element